# Python - stuck in codecademy training

Tags: python

stuck with codecamdemy - pls help

Starting with their example:

```
def sum(numbers):
    total = 0
    for number in numbers:
        total += number
    return total
n = [1, 2, 5, 10, 13]
print sum(n)
```

and some previously created listts/dictionaries:

```
shopping_list = ["banana", "orange", "apple"]
stock = {
    "banana": 6,
    "apple": 0,
    "orange": 32,
    "pear": 15
}
prices = {
    "banana": 4,
    "apple": 2,
    "orange": 1.5,
    "pear": 3
}
```

They ask to:
Define a function compute_bill that takes one argument food as input.
In the function, create a variable total with an initial value of zero.
For each item in the food list, add the price of that item to total.
Finally, return the total.

My code is not working:

```
# Write your code below!
def compute_bill(food):
    total = 0
    for x in food:
        total += x #or total+= int(x) or anything else I might think of
        return total
```

Note from codecademy:
Ignore whether or not the item you're billing for is in stock.
Note that your function should work for any food list.
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: what is food? It it some dictionary?

Comment: Please define *"not working"* - what exactly happens (error messages, expected and received input, what did you see when debugging, ...)

Comment: Is food dictionary?  you are returning total in a loop. Try returning outside of the loop.

Comment: food is just some random function attribute I gather,

Comment: return outside of loop: "Oops, try again. compute_bill(['apple']) resulted in a TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'"

Comment: I found the answer: total += prices[x]